# Video does not play from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video

I am building an iPhone 6 app for a friend's store. I wanted to have a video intro automatically playing when the initial view controller starts. I get no sound or audio.

I have on my storyboard a `UIViewController`, and in it a view that I re-classified as AVPlayerClass

I have also added added cupcake1.mov (QuickTime format) under "Supporting Files".

```
//  AppDelegate.h
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end

    //
//  AppDelegate.m
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end

    //
//  ViewController.h
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "AVPlayerClass.h"

@class AVPlayer;

@class AVPlayerClass;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerClass *playerView;


@end

    //
//  ViewController.m
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize player;

@synthesize playerView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupMovie];

}

- (void)setupMovie
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"cupcake1" withExtension:@"mov"];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: url];
    [self.playerView setMovieToPlayer:player];
    [self.player play];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

    //
//  AVPlayerClass+.h
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@class AVPlayer;

@interface AVPlayerClass : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer* player;

- (void)setMovieToPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player;

@end

    //
//  AVPalyerClass.m
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AVPlayerClass.h"

@implementation AVPlayerClass

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}

-(AVPlayer*)player
            {
                return [(AVPlayerLayer*) [self layer] player];
            }
- (void)setMovieToPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player
{
                [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] setPlayer: player];
            }
@end

    //
//  main.m
//  MovieUIView
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 28.03.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error showed?

Comment: no not all just shows AVPlayerClass

Comment: i am trying to get it work for the last 2 days (day and night) :) getting crazy

Comment: So what's your actual question which you want us to answer? Please try to specify it or isolate the problem.

Comment: in the View(AVPlayerClass) in the UIViewController it should automatically play the cupcake1.mov (contains also audio) but i got nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

I just created a sample project just like yours and have my movie playing and used the MPMoviePlayerController class.

I launched Xcode and created a new iOS application project based on the Single View Application template.

I took a random sample movie file from vimeo, downloaded it, and copied it to my project calling it "movie.mp4".

In the ViewController.m I followed the following three steps:

1. #import `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>>`
2. added a movieplayer property:

   @property (nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
3. in viewDidLoad I added the following code:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mp4"];
     NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
     self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

     self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
     self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
     [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

     UIView *videoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
     [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:videoView.bounds];
     [videoView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

     [self.view addSubview:videoView];

     [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
     [self.moviePlayer play];
   }
   ```

I built and run and I am able to watch the movie and go fullscreen.
I tested on device and the movie plays. 
If you get this far then you can adjust to your specific UI.
Hope this helps.

Comment: just, where i add the @property (nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;? and do i have to define a View as MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: added property to ViewController.h, is that correct? Where will it display now the movie?

Comment: got it. amazing. How can i now limited the video to an certain area

Comment: Now that you have it working you can go into the Storyboard and do Auto Layout and add some UI goodness.